# Return even if searched result partially matches the array of hash in ruby

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following in

```
 @name  = ["document1", "Public", "Folder11", "Folder22", "Folder33"]
```

If I do

```
@name.select { |str| str.include?(@searched) }
```

it will return me those values which partially match in the array
    e.g., If I do @name.include?("Folder") it gives me :

```
["Folder11", "Folder22", "Folder 33"]
```

Now I have the following in my array of hashes @combined_array:

```
 [{:id=>"folder.cecb8eb83d90dbeb.CECB8EB83D90DBEB!107", :name=>"Folder 11", :type=>"folder"}, {:id=>"folder.cecb8eb83d90dbeb.CECB8EB83D90DBEB!105", :name=>"Pictures", :type=>"album"}, {:id=>"folder.cecb8eb83d90dbeb.CECB8EB83D90DBEB!113", :name=>"Public", :type=>"folder"}, {:id=>"folder.cecb8eb83d90dbeb.CECB8EB83D90DBEB!124", :name=>"sasd", :type=>"folder"}, {:id=>"folder.cecb8eb83d90dbeb.CECB8EB83D90DBEB!108", :name=>"Folder12", :type=>"folder"}, {:id=>"folder.cecb8eb83d90dbeb.CECB8EB83D90DBEB!119", :name=>"Folder12", :type=>"folder"}, {:id=>"folder.cecb8eb83d90dbeb.CECB8EB83D90DBEB!115", :name=>"Folder13", :type=>"folder"}, {:id=>"file.cecb8eb83d90dbeb.CECB8EB83D90DBEB!121", :name=>"Document2.docx", :type=>"file"}, {:id=>"file.cecb8eb83d90dbeb.CECB8EB83D90DBEB!125", :name=>"sss.docx", :type=>"file"}]
```

I want to get the same result as above but this time with the array of hash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@combined_array =  [{:id=>"folder.cecb8eb83d90dbeb.CECB8EB83D90DBEB!107", :name=>"Folder 11", :type=>"folder"}, {:id=>"folder.cecb8eb83d90dbeb.CECB8EB83D90DBEB!105", :name=>"Pictures", :type=>"album"}, {:id=>"folder.cecb8eb83d90dbeb.CECB8EB83D90DBEB!113", :name=>"Public", :type=>"folder"}, {:id=>"folder.cecb8eb83d90dbeb.CECB8EB83D90DBEB!124", :name=>"sasd", :type=>"folder"}, {:id=>"folder.cecb8eb83d90dbeb.CECB8EB83D90DBEB!108", :name=>"Folder12", :type=>"folder"}, {:id=>"folder.cecb8eb83d90dbeb.CECB8EB83D90DBEB!119", :name=>"Folder12", :type=>"folder"}, {:id=>"folder.cecb8eb83d90dbeb.CECB8EB83D90DBEB!115", :name=>"Folder13", :type=>"folder"}, {:id=>"file.cecb8eb83d90dbeb.CECB8EB83D90DBEB!121", :name=>"Document2.docx", :type=>"file"}, {:id=>"file.cecb8eb83d90dbeb.CECB8EB83D90DBEB!125", :name=>"sss.docx", :type=>"file"}]
@combined_array.select { |item| item[:name].include?("Folder") }
=> [{:id=>"folder.cecb8eb83d90dbeb.CECB8EB83D90DBEB!107", :name=>"Folder 11", :type=>"folder"}, {:id=>"folder.cecb8eb83d90dbeb.CECB8EB83D90DBEB!108", :name=>"Folder12", :type=>"folder"}, {:id=>"folder.cecb8eb83d90dbeb.CECB8EB83D90DBEB!119", :name=>"Folder12", :type=>"folder"}, {:id=>"folder.cecb8eb83d90dbeb.CECB8EB83D90DBEB!115", :name=>"Folder13", :type=>"folder"}]
```

So instead of looking in a string

```
|str| str.include?(@searched)
```

You should look in an item (or hash) ie `item[:name]` is a string to search

```
|item| item[:name].include?(@searched)
```

Comment: I am not able to get any result. [29]pry(#<#Class:0x007f875d9d31e0>>)> @searched
=> "fol"
[30] pry(#<#<Class:0x007f875d9d31e0>>)> a
=> [{:id=>"folder.cecb8eb83d90dbeb.CECB8EB83D90DBEB!107", :name=>"Folder 11", :type=>"folder"},
 {:id=>"folder.cecb8eb83d90dbeb.CECB8EB83D90DBEB!105", :name=>"Pictures", :type=>"album"},
 {:id=>"folder.cecb8eb83d90dbeb.CECB8EB83D90DBEB!115", :name=>"Folder13", :type=>"folder"},
 {:id=>"file.cecb8eb83d90dbeb.CECB8EB83D90DBEB!121", :name=>"Document2.docx", :type=>"file"},
[31] pry(#<#<Class:0x007f875d9d31e0>>)> a.select { |item| item[:name].include?(@searched) }

Comment: I guess I need to down case the name